# How add rule to run autoreconf -vfi in debian/rules

Tags: debian

How do I add a rule to run autoreconf -vfi in debian/rules?

The upstream application ships an older version of libtool so I want to run autoreconf -vfi during the build.

Please help me to write debian/rules to run autoreconf -vfi and add commands to clean up after the build process.

debian rules:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
#export DH_VERBOSE=1

include /usr/share/quilt/quilt.make

DEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE   ?= $(shell dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE)
DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE  ?= $(shell dpkg-architecture -qDEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE)

CFLAGS += -Wall

config.status: configure patch
    dh_testdir
    ./configure --host=$(DEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE)     \
            --build=$(DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE)   \
            --prefix=/usr

build: build-arch build-indep
build-arch: build-stamp
build-indep: build-stamp

build-stamp:  config.status
    dh_testdir

    $(MAKE)

    touch build-stamp

clean: unpatch
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    rm -f build-stamp 

    [ ! -f Makefile ] || $(MAKE) distclean

    dh_clean
..............................................
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the debhelper add-on dh_autoreconf which will do this automatically.  You can add this to the beginning of your rules file:

```
%:
    dh $@  --with autoreconf
```

You can look [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man7/dh-autoreconf.7.html) for more info.  You might also have to add the dh-autoreconf package to your build dependencies.